# How can I detect that Google Website Translator is being used on my website?

Tags: google-translate

My website is available in English and French, but I still see people using Google Website Translator. How can I detect whether Google Website Translator is being used and tell users that the site is available in English and French?

On a side note, why does Google Website Translator ignore the below tag?

```
<link rel='alternate' hreflang='en' href='https://www.example.com/?lang=en'/>
```

Comment: Here’s how you can disable the translation: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7229002/2029790. But not sure if you can detect if a person is using English/French and then disable it.

Comment: I don't necessarily want to disable it. Instead I want to show a message with a link to the translated version.

Comment: Perhaps this answer helps you detect the translation: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4889433/2029790

Comment: @VincentOrback Thanks, came across that one. Seems outdated.

Comment: Well, at least you know that a class will be added so you could do something like `.translated-ltr .translation-links, .translated-rtl .translation-links{ display: block}` and show some links to your custom translation right?

Comment: @VincentOrback Just checked and the only class that's being added to the <body> tag is: e_md nj. Not sure what these stand for.