# Can web page translation by Google be detected?

Tags: javascript, php, google-translate

I have a web page, in Dutch, with a poll with a radio button.
I'd like to know which language the users speak. Is there a way I can detect if the page has been translated by Google when they submit?
I do not use a translation bar, I am talking about the spontaneous google translation.

Comment: This is done client side, so you cannot detect it. Inspect the accept-language header, but note that it is unreliable.

Comment: You can check the server logs to see if Google has accessed your site...

Comment: I don't know if there are many people that use Google in-browser translation a lot, and hence whether that is any useful indicator for what language the user speaks. Seems like a minor roundabout scenario to worry about…

Comment: It seem browser add class to `html` tag `class="translated-ltr"`

Comment: A theoretical idea: Use the onSubmit event to call a javascript function which look for a particular word. Put the result into a hidden field and then sumbit the form. On serverside create a list wich contains a range of translations for this word and compare it with submited value.

Comment: **See Also**: [Detecting Google Chrome Translation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4887156/1366033)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just check a known element if the text matches your text.

```
function isDutch() {
    return $('#readmore').text() === "Meer lezen";
}
```

or a non jQuery solution:

```
function isDutch() {
    document.querySelector('#readmore').innerText  === "Meer lezen";
}
```

Just make sure the element you have is an easy translatable sentence like read more.

Then you update a hidden field in your form with the result.

You can do this the moment a click is registered on your radio button.

I just tested it on a russian site, lenta.ru and ran `$('a[href="/parts/news"]').text();` after having translated it by right clicking the page and selecting translate this page(chrome). The content returned was in my language(dutch) in the jquery text().

[image: proof of translation detection]

Answer (score 2):

When translated through Google Translate, the target language is injected into the `lang` attribute of the main `html` tag, you can retrieve it with:

`document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].getAttribute('lang')`

which results in something like

`en-x-mtfrom-nl`... and this in turn you can log to your server or set as a cookie.

Comment: Actually, the lang attribute stays the same, but a class : translated-ltr is added. It shows : <html lang="nl" class="translated-ltr">. If I remove the lang attribute, it shows just : <html  class="translated-ltr">. This indicates a translation, but not in which language it is translated.